# Rotating A model in 3D so it matches its direction of movement

Tags: c++, mathematics, directx, rotation, transformation

So I have a model of a spear and when it gets thrown I want to set the orientation of the spear to its direction.  ( I also want to use this for other things like bullets pointing in the direction they are moving in)

my Models local forward Vector is +Z and I have the direction that it is moving in (in world space) from the velocity but I can't work out how to rotate it locally so that it is always pointing the right direction.

I tried to work out the difference in the angles and then create a Rotation matrix to apply to its rotation, but that didn't give me the desired results.

I am working in DirectX.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rebuild the spears orientation matrix from a direction vector.

Good example with dx code is here..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237873/rotate-a-sphere-so-that-its-pole-heads-towards-the-camera/4237921#4237921

Comment: Hmm, I understand the maths, but maybe a silly question but what would you then do with the orientation matrix?

Comment: I tried applying the orientation matrix as a rotation matrix on the current rotation of the object using D3DXVec3TransformCoord but that had very odd affects on the rotation

Comment: You dont apply it, you need to set it. The matrix you create is a replacement for the spear matrix.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand,  Where would I set this?

Comment: Please could you clarify how I would reset/ rebuild a models orientation matrix (at runtime)?

Comment: Unfortuinately I dont have time to set up a test dx project. The spear has a matrix. you would use it to rotate/translate the spear into the world. Replace it with the rebuilt matrix instead. The link shows how to rebuild the matrix.

Comment: Oh ok, Sorry I didn't realise you meant the objects World matrix.  I will give that a go.

Comment: Thanks.  Worked great.  Had to make one small adjustment though, the example points the up vector in the direction of forward.  This is ok if the models local orientation is correct for what you want.